# why my report viewer not display my current transaction values from database?

Tags: c#

i am working on window form application in C# that generate unique bill no from database.
i am using report viewer control.

after entering all detail of that customer's bill no when i click on print button,it can not display that current bill no's detail from database on report.

when i close my application and again start then it display 
i already tried but it not work for current value.

How can i fetch my current values on click of my print button. I tried but it does not not work on current values.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
this.Close(); Form2 f2 = new Form2(); f2.Show(); 
}
```

when click this button open report viewer form open and i write this code on page load event

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Bill_Detail order by billId DESC", cn); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
da.Fill(ds); 
int id = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());



    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
cn = new SqlConnection(databaseconnection); 
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Bill_Detail order by billId DESC", cn); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); da.Fill(ds); 
int id = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()); 
this.Customer_detailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.Customer_detail,id); 
this.Bill_DetailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet2.Bill_Detail, id); 
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport(); 
}
```

And i tried another way

```
     int id = Convert.ToInt32(Form1.lblbillno1);
    this.Customer_detailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.Customer_detail,id);             
     this.Bill_DetailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet2.Bill_Detail,id);
     reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
     this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport
```

Comment: paste your code for print button click event

Comment: private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.Close();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();                 
   }
when click this button open report viewer form open and i write this code on page load event
 int id=lblbillno.text;
 this.Customer_detailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.Customer_detail, id);
this.Bill_DetailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet2.Bill_Detail,id);

             this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

Comment: Please edit your post to put the code as part of the question. Also this button first closing itself and trying to open another form. I dont think Form2 will open.

Comment: Form2 will open.but data in report viewer not displayed.

Comment: my report viewer not displayed current billno's detail from databse.

Comment: Did you check DB is having the new insert? Also what is the id you get when you retrieve the data?

Comment: yes data is inserted.id is my current billid number and this billid number's detail i want to print on report viewer.

Comment: You are already getting the id in Form2 and all its related data? so what is problem? Where is the print command ? What is Form2 ? You may need to post the full code of Form2 to get some help

Comment: private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{cn = new SqlConnection(databaseconnection);
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Bill_Detail order by billId DESC", cn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
     this.Customer_detailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.Customer_detail,id);
           this.Bill_DetailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet2.Bill_Detail, id);
            
             this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
         }

Comment: i got billId from form1 but when click on print button form will open and form2 is my report viewer where i design my table.when click on print button  report viewer page is open but data related billid not displayes on report.

Comment: What is Dataset1 and Dataset2 ?? you are not filling them

Comment: dataset1 is my customer table and dataset2 is my bill_detail table in DB.

Comment: Are you *kidding*? You're doing a full `select * from Bill_Detail order by billId DESC` just to get the ID of the latest bill?? Oh boy...

Comment: i also tried it but does not work.

Comment: i tried in another way like:int id = Convert.ToInt32(Form1.lblbillno1);
    this.Customer_detailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.Customer_detail,id);             
     this.Bill_DetailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet2.Bill_Detail,id);
     reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
     this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();but also not work.

Comment: Well, this indicates that something else is wrong, doesn't it? Anyone must see that querying ALL the data from a table that may grow endlessly just to get ONE value is a bad approach! The *very least* you should do is a `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY billId DESC`, if not execute a separate `SqlCommand` with `ExecuteScalar`.